# How to fix the error message to my following SQL query: "cannot call jsonb_each on a non-object"?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT
    "PersonType" AS (SELECT (jsonb_each("person"."sources")).key AS "DiffTypes",
    "person"."id"
FROM 
    "person" 
JOIN 
    "BuyersOnly" ON "person"."id"::text = "BuyersOnly"."actPersons"
WHERE
    "person"."sources" IS NOT NULL
    AND "BuyersOnly"."actPersons" IS NOT NULL
    AND jsonb_typeof("person"."sources")='object')
```

I am expecting a joined table

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected as texts ? also explain what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Your code example is not valid.  It looks like it has been mangled in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `WHERE` condition is evaluated first:

```
WITH cte AS MATERIALIZED (
   SELECT id, sources
   FROM person
      JOIN "BuyersOnly"
         ON person.id::text = "BuyersOnly"."actPersons"
   WHERE person.sources IS NOT NULL
     AND "BuyersOnly"."actPersons" IS NOT NULL
     AND jsonb_typeof(person.sources)='object'
)
SELECT e.key, cte.id
FROM cte
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(cte.sources) AS e;
```